# Probability with three parts

Tags: probability

Suppose that a town has the population of $100$ and $10$ of them are infected with HIV. Assume that currently Sasha is not infected and that if she meets with a group of one or more people that includes a infected person, then she will get infected.

$(a)$ What is the probability that she will get infected when she meets with one person?

$(b)$ What is the probability that she will get infected when she meets with two persons?

$(c)$ What is the probability that she will get infected when she meets with three persons?

It seems working backwards would be beneficial for solving this problem. Namely, probability that she will not get infected when she meets with $k$ people would be $\frac{C(89,k)}{C(99,k)}$, thus desired answer will be $1 - \frac{C(89,k)}{C(99,k)}$?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Pl. show what effort you have made, else you aren't likely to get answers

Comment: Your answer to $a$ is not quite correct.  Sasha can't meet with herself so the answer is $\frac {10}{99}$.

Comment: Why $\frac{10}{100}$? She can meet only others ($99$).

Comment: Hint for the other parts: it is considerably easier to work backwards.  That is, if you take a group of $k$ people, compute the probability that none of them are infected.

Comment: I modified my problem statement, does it seem to return true answers for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt for part (a) is incorrect, I'll show  you how to start for part (b), you should then be able to finish it and do the other parts.

Leaving out Sasha, there are $10$ infected in the $99$ remaining people.

P(Sasha is **not** infected meeting $2$ persons) $= \frac{89}{99}\cdot\frac{88}{98}$

So what is P(Sasha **is** infected) ?

Comment: I mean the original statement, finding the desired answer for any k?

Comment: yes, it is now correct.